# Setting the value of an Enum field in a temporary record

Tags: testing, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

Total newbie in AL here; I'm experimenting with automated testing in Dynamics BC for a new deployment. As a very basic test, I'd like to simply create a new Item record in the Cronus test database and validate each field. I'm running into trouble when I try to select the value for an enum field. Here's the code I'm using:

```
Procedure AddGoodItem()
// [Given] Good item data
var
    recItem: Record Item Temporary; 
Begin
    recItem."Description" := 'zzzz';
    recItem.validate("Description");
    recItem.Type := recItem.Type::Inventory;
    recItem.Validate(Type);
    recItem."Base Unit of Measure" := 'EA';
    recItem.Validate("Base Unit of Measure");
    recItem."Item Category Code" := 'FURNITURE';
    recItem.validate("Item Category Code");
End;
```

When I run this in Cronus, I get the error:

```
You cannot change the Type field on Item  because at least one Item Journal Line exists for this item.
```

If I comment the Type lines out, the process runs successfully.

Given that this is a temporary record, it shouldn't have any Item Journal Lines, should it? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the `OnValidate` trigger still runs, even if you have marked the `Record` variable as `temporary`. In addition `temporary` is not inherited to the underlying variables meaning any `Record` variables used in the `OnValidate` trigger are not `temporary` (unless marked as such).

There are two options:

1. Leave out the line `recItem.Validate(Type);`, if the code run by the OnValidate trigger is not relevant in this case.
2. Replace the line `recItem.Validate(Type);` with your own clone of the code from the `OnValidate` trigger and then remove the unneeded parts.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense